# How to Append 'GRAND TOTAL' Row at the End of a DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a Pandas DataFrame and I want to add a 'GRAND TOTAL' row at the end of it. This row should contain sums of specific numeric columns and should always be at the bottom of the DataFrame, even after sorting by index.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```py
total = new_df.sum(numeric_only=True)
total.name = 'GRAND TOTAL'
total_df = total.to_frame().T
total_df.at['GRAND TOTAL', 'CURRENCY'] = ''
total_df.at['GRAND TOTAL', 'MANDATE'] = 'SomeValue'
total_df.at['GRAND TOTAL', 'COMPOSITE'] = 'GRAND TOTAL'

new_df = pd.concat([new_df, total_df.set_index('COMPOSITE')])
new_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

When I run this, the 'GRAND TOTAL' row doesn't stay at the end after sorting.

How can I make sure that the 'GRAND TOTAL' row is always at the end of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) with unique categories, last item is `GRAND TOTAL`:

```
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, total_df.set_index('COMPOSITE')])

cats = list(new_df.index.difference(['GRAND TOTAL']).unique()) + ['GRAND TOTAL']

new_df.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(new_df.index, categories=cats, ordered=True)
new_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Or if all items are unique in `Index` is possible use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, total_df.set_index('COMPOSITE')])

cats = list(new_df.index.difference(['GRAND TOTAL']).unique()) + ['GRAND TOTAL']
new_df = new_df.reindex(cats)
```